# Lookup data from two ranges and if text matches, then assign numeric value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am trying to calculate points in a Formula 1 racing league. I'm having trouble with a bonus 15 points if a constructor qualifies 1st and finishes the race 1st. The issue is there could be two different drivers who do this. For example. As you can see, HAM qualified 1st and ROS finished 1st in the race. Because they both drive for Mercedes, 15 points need to be awarded to Mercedes. The data can't be moved around as it's imported using an API (not in the example) but [a copy of the layout can be found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IbGHyW3FDYHpX46tMIwv6Z0pgjM0GFyAu9tk2o4Hg_g/edit?usp=sharing)

`Qualifying Race Driver Team

14  1   ROS mercedes
1   15  HAM mercedes
3   3   VET ferrari
8   4   RIC red_bull
6   5   MAS williams
19  6   GRO haas
10  7   HUL force_india
16  8   BOT williams
7   9   SAI toro_rosso
5   10  VES toro_rosso
13  11  PAL renault`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in I2 and copy down. See if that is how you want it:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(1, $A$2:$H$12, 8, FALSE)=VLOOKUP(1, $B$2:$H$12, 7, FALSE), VLOOKUP(1, $B$2:$H$12, 7, FALSE)=H2, MATCH(H2, H:H, 0)=ROW(H2)), 15, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Marc, that's fantastic. Now I'm going to examine it so I can fully understand it :)